# daterangepicker set no dates

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

I have a daterangepicker (http://www.daterangepicker.com/) setup on my site:

[image]

With this code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[id="searchDateRange"]').daterangepicker({
        timePickerSeconds: true,
        autoApply: true,
        startDate: "${defaultStart}",
        endDate: "${defaultEnd}",
        timePicker: true,
        locale: {
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS'
        },
        ranges: {
           'Past 24 Hours': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment()],
           'Today': [moment().startOf('day'), moment().endOf('day')],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day'), moment().subtract(1, 'days').endOf('day')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
           'None': [null, null]
        }
    });


    var history = document.querySelector('.history');
    if (history) {
        new Tablesort(history);
    }
});
```

When I select "None" I'd like it to set the field to blank, but instead it sets the value to "Invalid Date - Invalid Date":

[image]

Is there a way to blank out the field based on the selection?

Comment: You should set an empty string value as they described,
they give an example with clear button:
http://www.daterangepicker.com/#example5

Comment: The clear button is nice, but requires you to select "Custom Range" before it's presented as an option which is not what I was hoping.

Comment: It's just an example that shows how to use clear function as User863 wrote in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`apply.daterangepicker`](http://www.daterangepicker.com/#events) event and moment's [`isValid()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/is-valid/)

```js
$('input[id="searchDateRange"]').daterangepicker({
  timePickerSeconds: true,
  autoApply: true,
  //startDate: "${defaultStart}",
  //endDate: "${defaultEnd}",
  timePicker: true,
  locale: {
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss:SSS'
  },
  ranges: {
    'Past 24 Hours': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment()],
    'Today': [moment().startOf('day'), moment().endOf('day')],
    'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days').startOf('day'), moment().subtract(1, 'days').endOf('day')],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')],
    'None': [null, null]
  }
});

$('input[id="searchDateRange"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  if (!picker.startDate.isValid() || !picker.endDate.isValid()) {
    $(this).val('')
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/latest/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" id="searchDateRange" />
```

Comment: How do you run the function on page load too? i.e., when I hit "Go" the page loads the data into a form and the form then sets the value in the field. So when I reload the page it goes back to "Invalid date - invalid date"

Comment: @ryvantage try `$('input[id="searchDateRange"]').val('')` on page load after `daterangepicker` initialisation

Comment: @User863 This solution seems to be breaking if we click on the `Custom Range` after clicking on the `None`. Do you think if there is any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answer is a very good solution and better than this. You can also try this code:-

```
$('input[id="searchDateRange"]').on('change', function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Invalid date - Invalid date')
    {
        $(this).val(" ");
    }
});
```